# Cronjob on CentOS, upload files via scp and delete on success

Tags: bash, ssh, cron, centos

I'm running CentOS 6.

I need to upload some files every hour to another server.

I have SSH access with password to the server. But ssh-keys etc. is not an option.

Can anyone help me out with a .sh script that uploads the files via scp and delete the original after a successful upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I'd suggest to use rsync rather than scp, as it is far more powerful. Just put the following in an executable script. Here, I assume that all the files (and nothing more) is in the directory pointed to by local_dir/.

```
#!/bin/env bash
rsync -azrp --progress --password-file=path_to_file_with_password \
local_dir/ remote_user@remote_host:/absolute_path_to_remote_dir/
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then 
echo "Something went wrong: don't delete local files."
else
rm -r local_dir/
fi
```

The options are as follows (for more info, see, e.g., http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html):

```
 -a, --archive               Archive mode
 -z, --compress              Compress file data during the transfer
 -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
 -p, --perms                 Preserve permissions
     --progress              Show progress during transfer
     --password-file=FILE    Get password from FILE
     --delete-after          Receiver deletes after transfer, not during
```

***Edit: removed --delete-after, since that's not the OP's intent***

Be careful when setting the permissions for the file containing the password. Ideally only you should have access tot he file.

As usual, I'd recommend to play a bit with rsync in order to get familiar with it. It is best to check the return value of rsync (using $?) before deleting the local files.

More information about rsync: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rsync.htm

Comment: I do have some files in the directory, that shouldn't be uploaded and not deleted. Is that possible?

Comment: Just found out that rsync deletes all the files in my remote folder, which does not exists i the local folder. Not good. I think scp will be better for this issue or?

Comment: @user809829: Yes, that's the purpose of --delete-after. You can remove that option and it won't delete the files. There's no reason to use scp over rsync, as the latter is more powerful. You can also experiment on what rsync does using the --dry-run option, which will only show the operations it will perform. As in every case, you should read the man pages, they contain _a lot_ of information.

Comment: Oh, did not know that. Thank you. I read the man pages as delete-after just waited to delete files (on remote server as well) after copying new files, instead of before/during the file transfers.

Comment: It does seems as the password-file does not work? I've been reading up upon it at it has something to do with rsync should be run as a daemon. I've tried with --daemon but that still reports errors.

Comment: Yes, this requires you to run rsync as a daemon on the remote host. See, e.g., http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2011/01/running-rsync-as-a-daemon.html. All this depends on what kind of access you have on the remote machine. I don't know why ssh keys are not an option (I guess admin policy), but that's by far the easiest.